# Multiple Rails projects with different databases for each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I'm new to Rails and after going through the Heroku tutorial I've set up a project using PostgresQL.

A friend also learning Rails followed a different tutorial which used SQLite as the database, which I've cloned.

When starting the rails server with the SQLite project, I'm continually getting an error suggesting that the project is trying to use PostgresQL and telling me to add `gem pg` to my Gemfile.

All I can seem to find online are various posts about migrating to PostgresQL from MySQL/SQLite/etc, but I am not looking to migrate.

My database.yml is as follows:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

The error reported in RubyMine is:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/Ty/Rails/TSCLunch/web/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/Ty/Rails/TSCLunch/web/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Ty/Rails/TSCLunch/web/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Ty/Rails/TSCLunch/web/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/Ty/Rails/TSCLunch/web/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Ty/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Ty/Rails/TSCLunch/web/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from /Users/Ty/Rails/TSCLunch/web/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is there a DATABASE_URL environment variable ? (Does `echo $DATABASE_URL` output anything )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify adapter to the ActiveRecord in two ways.

1. Using `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` environment variable
2. Using `database.yml` configuration file

If you have both config/database.yml and ENV['DATABASE_URL'] set then Rails will merge the configuration together. I think this is what causes your problem.

If it is so, you can remove your environmental variable or specify url  explicitly in your `database.yml`

I encourage you to read the following article for more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: This solved my issue. I'll add a note that even after doing this and reloading my `.bash_profile`, it still persisted. Not sure why, but once I restarted my computer it was working correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just want to get a project that 'works' locally and NOT on heroku, regardless if it's using Postgres or SQLITE3, yeah?

Can you post a copy of your Gemfile as well?  Since you followed the Heroku tutorial, it is unclear from your post what other steps you followed, except that you probably created your app by running this on the commandline:

$> rails new myapp --database=postgresql

This would add "gem 'pg'" to your Gemfile and it would create an appropriate database.yml for it.  But then if you copied over the other database.yml specifying SQLITE3, now your Rails environment is confused.

If you do have 'gem pg' in your Gemfile, try the following steps:

1) in your Gemfile, remove that 'pg' line and replace it with:
gem 'sqlite3'

2) do a 'bundle install' to install SQLITE3 which your cloned database.yml specifies anyways.

3) run the following command to reset your databases:
$> rake db:reset

Hopefully that will get you going again.  Now you should have a project that is using SQLITE3 rather than Postgres.  You won't be able to deploy it to Heroku, though since they don't allow SQLITE3 for production.

If you get it working locally with SQLITE3 and later want to deploy to Heroku, they provide a simple procedure on moving back to Postgres from SQLITE3 here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Comment: Unfortunately doing a `rake db:reset` just threw the same exceptions. The `gem pg` line was not present in my Gemfile, just the `gem sqlite3`.